# map.setcenter & map.setzoom not working properly

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a left side menu bar which when someone clicks on the a link, it jumps to the marker location on the map.  This works fine.

But, I'd like to update this so that as they click the link in the left-side bar, the map centers on the marker and zooms to a certain level.  But this isn't working proplerly.

The error I'm receiving in Firebug is:

```
missing ) after argument list
map.setCenter(latlng:latLng);
```

Code:

```
<div id="LeftArea" style="width: 220px; float: left; border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede; padding: 5px 0 5px 0;">
    <div style="color: #a41d21;font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold;">
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            document.write('<a href="javascript:myclick(' + (i) + ')">' + '[[Title]]' + '<\/a><br>');
        </script>
    </div>
    <div>
        [[Address]]<br />
        [[City]], [[State]] [[Zip]]
    </div>
</div>

myclick = function(i) {
  google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], "click");
}

// Associate the markers with the links in the side bar.
  gmarkers[i] = marker;

// Display the info window when someone clicks on a marker or it's associated side bar link.
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
    map.setCenter(latlng:latLng);
    map.setzoom(zoom: 16);
    InfoWindow.setContent(this.html);
    InfoWindow.open(map, this);
  });
```

Comment: I was able to get it working properly.  Edited the code as follows:  "map.setCenter(this.position);map.setZoom(16);".  Thanks..

Comment: I was able to get the setmapcenter and setmapzoom working properly.

But, how would I go about resetting the MapTypeID?

I tried the following code, but it's not working properly.

    map.setMapTypeId(ROADMAP);

But the map isn't changing back to the Roadmap style map and Firebug is reporting:

"ROADMAP is not defined"

Thanks..

Comment: Got this second part figured out as well:
map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP);
Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

`map.setCenter()` and `map.setZoom()` need specific arguments, and the documentation doesn't really help with its syntax.

`map.setCenter()` requires a `LatLng` object:

```
myLatLng=  new google.maps.LatLng(0,0);
map.setCenter(myLatLng);
```

`map.setZoom()` takes a simple integer: for example `map.setZoom(16);`

Colons have a particular use in object definitions, but have no place here. This is what is causing your error message.

Additional issue: what is latLng here...?
`map.setCenter(latlng:latLng);`

That will need to be defined somewhere. Perhaps you want the map centred on the marker?

`map.setCenter(this.getPosition());`

Comment: NB: The `.position` attribute mentioned in the OP comment is not documented. Use the documented method `.getPosition()`.